# how to use two submitt in one jsp and call two actions

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

i am working with spring mvc framework. i have two submit buttons on a page. that are forwarding request to two different controller. how can i use two action on single jsp page .
please suggest.

my controller are as

1.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/reset", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String editUser(@ModelAttribute("users") User user,
                BindingResult result) {
            Integer uid=user.getId();
            User resetUser = usersService.findUser(uid);
            resetUser.setActive(0);
            ResetPasswordLog resetPasswordLog=new ResetPasswordLog();
            usersService.addUsers(resetUser);
            resetPasswordLogService.setTempHash(uid);
            String TEMPHASH= resetPasswordLog.getTempHash();
            System.out.println("www.lacas.com/reset?uid="+uid+"&th="+TEMPHASH);
            return "redirect:/secure/user/" + uid;

            }
```

2.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("users") UserForm userForm,
            BindingResult result) {
        Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        User user = usersService.findUser(userForm.getId());
        Integer userId = userForm.getId();

        User newUser = usersService.findUser(userForm.getEmail());
        user.setName(userForm.getName());
        if (newUser == null) {
            user.setEmail(userForm.getEmail());
            user.getRoles().clear();
            Integer[] roleIds = userForm.getRoleIds();
            for (Integer roleId : roleIds) {
                if (roleId != 0) {
                    Role role = roleService.findRole(roleId);
                    user.getRoles().add(role);
                }
            }
            usersService.addUsers(user);
            return "redirect:/secure/users/index";

        } else {

            edit_exist_user = true;
            return "redirect:/secure/user/" + userId;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can by using JavaScript, and changing form's `action` attribute dynamically. If this is your form:

```
<form id="myform" action="#" onsubmit="return pickDestination();">
    <input type="submit" name="sbmitbtn" value="edit" onclick="document.pressed=this.value"/>
    <input type="submit" name="sbmitbtn" value="reset" onclick="document.pressed=this.value"/>
</form>
```

Then your `pickDestination` JS function would look like:

```
function pickDestination()
{
    var a = "/user/" + document.pressed;
    document.getElementById("myform").action = a;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: how?? can you please give me an example

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to preface this by saying that I'm not very familiar with spring applications, however in many other java based MVC systems I've accomplished this by simply giving my submit buttons a name and parsing off this in the action class by checking the request.

For example find which submit button was used by it's parameter name, call the appropriate methods. The following is an example of a struts based solution I use on occasion. If you can access the servlet request object in your spring controller, you could do something similar.

```
@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
    try {
        // Check the request for a someone clicking the logout submit button
        if (found("logout")) {
            user.logout(); //invoke the logout method
            session.remove("user");
            return SUCCESS;
        }

        // Check the request for a someone clicking the login submit button
        if (found("login")) {
            user.login();
            session.put("user", user);          
            return "login";
        }

    // Catch any login exceptions
    } catch (Exception e) {
        user = null;
        addActionError(e.getMessage());
        return INPUT;
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}

// The following method checks for a request paramater based on the key (String)
// provided. If the key is not found or the value for the parameters is empty, it 
// returns false;
private boolean found(String param) {
    Object temp = request.getParameter(param);
    if (temp != null) {
        if (temp.toString().isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```